# Can not convert nvarchar into double or so on

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table with a column `SalaryActualYear` which is unfortunately `nvarchar(254)`. I have to convert it to double, float, numeric or decimal.

What I do:

```
SELECT 
       [FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[SalaryActualYear]
      ,cast(SalaryActualYear as  NUMERIC(2,2))
FROM [CW_StagingArea].[dbo].[tbl_LN_MBO_Master_Data]

SELECT 
       [FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[SalaryActualYear]
      ,cast(SalaryActualYear as DECIMAL(2,2))
FROM [CW_StagingArea].[dbo].[tbl_LN_MBO_Master_Data]

SELECT 
       [FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[SalaryActualYear]
      ,convert(FLOAT,SalaryActualYear)
FROM [CW_StagingArea].[dbo].[tbl_LN_MBO_Master_Data]

SELECT 
       [FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[SalaryActualYear]
      ,convert(DOUBLE ,SalaryActualYear)
FROM [CW_StagingArea].[dbo].[tbl_LN_MBO_Master_Data]
```

Unfortunately, in every case I get an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.
>
> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.
>
> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
> Incorrect syntax near ','.

So I'm really confused. Please help me what should I do.

Comment: what is the value of `SalaryActualYear` ??

Comment: What do the values in that column actually look like at the moment? And are they all similar or are there a variety of formats?

Comment: "SalaryActualYear which is unfortunately nvarchar(254). " - that is one of the worst design decisions I can remember! Also, don't use double to represent money. Not if you want to keep your job! Then again, in light of the previous design decision it probably won't matter!!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  declare @v nvarchar(50) = '21.89777777777777777777777777'

    select convert(decimal(18,2),round(@v,2))
```

`you can also use isNumeric on the column to find the required data.`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
      cast(Round(SalaryActualYear,2) as DECIMAL(2,2))
FROM [CW_StagingArea].[dbo].[tbl_LN_MBO_Master_Data]

Here, nvarchar was basically introduced to store the extended characters such as in from Chinese language. So if your field contains that data, you will have an issue.

Also ROUND function here will convert the empty strings into decimal equivalent to 0. If you have that data as well you need to check for that. NULL values would be taken care off automatically up here.

This should work.